# How do I change the text inside a textarea in PyScript?

Tags: html, textarea, pyscript

I am making a programme where you type something in, click a button, then it gets processed and the output gets placed on a textarea. However, the textarea does not update. I would ideally not `import js` to do this.

I tried assigning `Element("textarea-id").element.value` a different value, but the textarea remained unchanged. I tried googling, but the closest I could find is how to do it in JavaScript. As I said, I do not want to `import js`.

Comment: Can't you just write in in plain html?  `<textarea id="textarea-id">{{ py_value }}</textarea>` --   And just change the `py_value` variable?

Comment: @Zak i actually never knew about that... let me try.

Comment: @Zak that doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Without your code it's impossible to tell. I am assuming you're running a static page in Python.  Which means you will need to `POST` or `GET`  the value in your `<input>` to the page and then set it the way I described above.  Without a JavaScript handler, it's impossible without a page reload.

Comment: Added an answer below, but I'm curious why you don't want to `import js`? The `Element` class does so under the hood, and indeed the interpreter does `import js` prior to loading user code anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example achieving what you're looking for. I'm not sure why your use of `Element('xxx').element.value` didn't work without more context, since it should work fine (and does for me).

I've included explicit links to PyScript 2023.05.1 to make use of the new `@when` decorator. This could also be achieved using the `py-click` attribute or manually adding event listeners in older versions of PyScript.

```html
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2023.05.1/pyscript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/releases/2023.05.1/pyscript.css">

<input type="text" id="inp">
<button id="btn">Submit</button>
<textarea id="area" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

<py-script>
    from pyscript import when 

    @when('click', "#btn")
    def set_text_area():
        content = Element("inp").element.value
        content = content * 2 # do some text processing here
        Element("area").element.value = content
</py-script>
```